# Is it possable to stream images to a PDF using tesseract?

Tags: pdf-generation, python-tesseract, stream-processing

I need to stream images from a scanner to a PDF document. Ultimately I want to OCR the images and save the text to the PDF as well, but I'm more concerned with getting the streaming working first. Right now I'm trying the different Python wrappers for tesseract, but I'm open to other languages if the Python wrappers are too limited (Java?).

While this topic may seem to have been addresses ad nauseam most of the discussion centers on passing a list of a directory full of files. The challenge here is that I'm dealing with documents with upwards of 10,000 images so buffering them all entirely in memory first or building the PDF entirely in memory is not possible, and I'm trying to avoid having to write 10,000 images to a tmp directory and then come back and touch them again with a 2nd pass. From a simplified high level the following semantics is what I'm looking for.

```
# pseudocode
f = pdfOutputStream.open("myPDFFileName", "wb")
for image in scannerImages.next(): 
    f.appendImageToPDF(image)
f.finalize()
f.close()
```

Is that even possible, and if so, what would my options be?

Comment: The scanners are Fujitsu M4097D and fi-7160. The env. is Openshift on Openstack. Sane used for image acquisition. Image processing pipeline includes barcode separator detection with property key/value extraction, blank page detection, transcoding to optimal image type, OCR, auto-image rotation and deskew, JPEG compression, and streaming images to a PDF container with metadata. In order to simplify the question I've omitted the irrelevant details. Tessaeract is the OCR engine of choice here and is able to write pdf containers, so I'm interested in whether it can serve both functions.

Comment: I've been architecting Doc. Mgmt.solutions for fortune 500 financial services enterprises for more than 2 decades, so I know a thing or two, and the architecture is off topic. The topic of this question is specific to the tesseract API and the ability, or not, to stream images to a PDF container. It looks like Tesseract can do it if you're writing C++ code but none of the Python wrappers seem to expose the necessary classes and functions. The documentation is not exactly verbose and I can find no such example, so I'd like to hear from someone more knowledgeable than myself in this area.

Comment: That is an example of how to write a Tesseract OCR wrapper using ctypes, not how to use an existing Python wrapper, like [tesserocr](https://github.com/sirfz/tesserocr) or [aiopytesseract](https://github.com/amenezes/aiopytesseract). The same can be accomplished with pybind11. Before writing my own wrapper I'm interested in eliminating the possibility of using existing Python, or other, wrappers. There is no point is wasting time reinventing the wheel if an acceptable one already exists,

Comment: I'm effectively writing my own app. due to limitations in available commercial products. The closest equivalent is Capture from Kofax, which does most of what's needed, but is Windows only, relies too heavily on human workflow for document assembly and indexing, and is not cost effective for what it provides. I'm adding enhancements like index parameters in separator sheets and AI image classification and indexing to automate and streamline the pipeline so the manual indexing task is as minimal as possible. I'm not writing the 80% that commercial packages do, I'm writing the 20% they don't do.